# Get the computed value of a formula in Excel using Apache POI 3.14

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

**Update 2**: Well for some reason I completely forgot to mention that the cell I am trying to access is actually summing up cells that contain formulas themselves. These cells contain a `SUMIF` formula as such:

> =SUMIF('Sheet1'!B2:B4,DATE(2016,8,31),'Sheet1'!E2:E4)

So my reasoning was that I had to evaluate these cells **before** evaluating the actual cell I need, and this is where the `FormulaEvaluator` isn't working correctly. In other words, the simple `SUM` function is evaluating as intended, but is mistakenly summing up `0.0` from the cells containing the `SUMIF` functions. I tried using `evaluator.sumInCell()` every time I would update a cell containing the `SUMIF` function, but that is evaluating into `0.0` as well.

Does it have to do with the libraries not supporting the `SUMIF` function? Or maybe I should change the condition?

=========================================================================

**Update**: Okay so I only managed to get the correct value by manually opening the excel file and then closing it right after. I would get a prompt to save my changes to the file when in fact I made none. I imagine there's something wrong with how I am generating and manipulating the file.

```
private void createDataFile(File dataFile) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
    XSSFWorkbook  workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    //
    // Code to create and populate rows and cells
    //

    workBook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}

private void updateSheet(File dataFile) throws IOException {
    Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(dataFile));
    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(0);

    //
    // Code to update and manipulate cells
    //

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
    workBook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

**Note:** I am only able to read the value through `cell.getNumericCellValue()`, `FormulaEvaluator` still doesn't work either way.

=========================================================================

Hello I am trying to read a value computed using a formula in an excel sheet.
The formula is a simple sum function as follows: `SUM(B2:B6)`.

Using Apache POI 3.14 libraries, I came up with the following snippet of code:

```
public Double getCellValue() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{
    Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File("data.xlsx")));
    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

    // i only need one specific cell, at the last row in my sheet
    Row row = sheet.getRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);

    // this is where I am stuck
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
    return cellValue.getNumberValue();
}
```

I made sure that I am targeting the correct cell, however this method returns `0.0` instead of the correct computed value.

I initially tried a different approach using `cell.getNumericCellValue()` instead of `FormulaEvaluator`, however that was giving me the same incorrect result, `0.0`.

After going through the documentation online, I failed to find an explanation to my problem, any insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure that what you think is the last row of your spreadsheet is actually the last row of your spreadsheet, as stored in the file? Did you try printing out the row number just to be sure?

Comment: Rows/Cells are indexed 0-based, so Row "1" is at index 0 and so forth, did you take that into account? Take a look at cell.toString() and see if it actually returns the formula.

Comment: Yes, I've already went through these troubleshooting steps. I am able to print out the formula held in the cell, the correct row and column numbers, but not the actual value computed from the formula @Gagravarr

Comment: seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649918/formula-evaluator-in-apache-poi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716664/apache-poi-evaluate-formula?rq=1?

Comment: @RC. Yes, both of which did not help much

Comment: Thank you for this Question and the indirect help it gave me. I was desperately searching for a way to reference another Sheet in my Workbook but couldn't find a way to insert the `$` into my Formula without `FormulaParseException Parse error near char 4 '$'.` Now I know that I have to insert it like you did: without $ but with ! `String sSum = "\'"+oArrListSheetNames.get(1)+"\'!"+oCell.getReference()+""`

Answer (score 2):

With

[image: data.xlsx content]

This works for me:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public final class Demo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getCellValue());
    }

    public static Double getCellValue() throws Exception {
        final Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File("data.xlsx")));
        final Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        // i only need one specific cell, at the last row in my sheet
        final Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
        final Cell cell = row.getCell(0); // formula in A2
        System.err.println(cell.getCellFormula());

        // this is where I am stuck
        final FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        final CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        return cellValue.getNumberValue();
    }
}
```

output:

```
SUM(B2:B6)
15.0
```

So I assume there is some issue with your way to get the cell, or the xlsx content. Using a debugger, you should be able to figure out whats wrong